# Insert While Loop SQL Server - Fast at first, grinds to a halt

Tags: sql-server, database, indexing, while-loop

I have been tasked to replicate a large amount of data being entered into our application database to see how it would perform.

I have produced the following while loop,

```
DECLARE @DATABASESID uniqueidentifier
SET @DATABASESID = (SELECT SID FROM mcm_system)

DECLARE @START_MIN_PROCESS INT;
SET @START_MIN_PROCESS = 200000;

WHILE @START_MIN_PROCESS > 1
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRAN
        INSERT INTO READING (ID, SID, POINT_DETAIL_ID, TAKEN, VALUE, STATUS, POINT_DATA_ID, WHO, MACHINE_STATE, RESTORED_ID, JOTTING, TAG, VALUEA, VALUEB, VALUEC)
           SELECT 
               NEWID(), @DATABASESID, Point_Detail.ID, 
               DATEADD(MINUTE, -@START_MIN_PROCESS, GETDATE()), ABS(CHECKSUM(NewId())) % 60, 
               'N', '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000',
               @USERID, '', '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000',
               '', 'N', 0, 0, 0 
           FROM 
               POINT_DETAIL 
           WHERE 
               TYPE = 0
    PRINT DATEADD(MINUTE, -@START_MIN_PROCESS, GETDATE())
    SET @START_MIN_PROCESS = @START_MIN_PROCESS - 15;

    COMMIT
END
```

The point_detail table referenced has 9000 records and the loop is designed to insert a record with a random value, and a date in the past for every `point_detail` record. The date is then incremented 15 minutes into the future and the loop runs again. I use the Print to keep track of progress as I am trying to replicate a years worth of data.

It runs fine at first and eventually grinds to a halt. Is there any way I can optimize my statement or another alternative method?

Comment: Why does it get slow?   What are the wait stats for the session running the code? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-session-wait-stats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: I'm pretty sure the `PRINT` statements will eventually lag (seen that it long running scripts). Using `RAISERROR(blablabla',10,1) WITH NOWAIT;` will not lag (though output will eventually cluster IIRC). One more (perhaps superfluous) suggestion: start the whole batch with `SET NOCOUNT ON;`.